# How do I dismiss the parent fragment when on clicking an item in the recyclerview on the bottom sheet, which contains the layout tab and viewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2, android-bottomsheetdialog

**This is my main activity.**

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            ...

            R.id.menu_table_of_content -> {
                hideOrShowView()
                ReaderTabFragment.newInstance(tocItems.toTypedArray()).show(
                        supportFragmentManager,
                        ReaderTabFragment::class.java.simpleName
                    )
                true
            }

            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

**This is my bottom sheet dialog fragment.**

```
class ReaderTabFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentReaderTabBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding as FragmentReaderTabBinding
    private lateinit var readerTabAdapter: ReaderTabViewPagerAdapter

    private var navItem: Array<NavigationItem>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.TransparentBackgroundDialog)

        arguments?.let {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            navItem = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                it.getParcelableArray(ARG_NAV_ITEM, NavigationItem::class.java)
            } else {
                it.getParcelableArray(ARG_NAV_ITEM) as Array<NavigationItem>
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).apply {
            (this as? BottomSheetDialog)?.behavior?.apply {
                skipCollapsed = true
                state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
                setPeekHeight(resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels, true)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentReaderTabBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        initView()
    }

    private fun initView() {
        readerTabAdapter =
            ReaderTabViewPagerAdapter(parentFragmentManager, lifecycle, navItem ?: emptyArray())

        val tabTitles = arrayOf(
            getString(R.string.text_reader_toc_menu),
            getString(R.string.text_reader_collection_bookmark_menu)
        )
        binding.viewPager.apply {
            offscreenPageLimit = 2
            adapter = readerTabAdapter
        }
        TabLayoutMediator(
            binding.tabLayout, binding.viewPager
        ) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = tabTitles[position]
        }.attach()
    }

    override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog)
        _binding = null
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: Array<NavigationItem>) =
            ReaderTabFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putParcelableArray(ARG_NAV_ITEM, param1)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**This is my viewPager adapter.**

```
class ReaderTabViewPagerAdapter(
    fm: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    private val navItem: Array<NavigationItem>
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 2

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        val fragment: Fragment = when (position) {
            0 -> TableOfContentFragment.newInstance(navItem)
            1 -> BookmarkFragment()
            else -> TableOfContentFragment.newInstance(navItem)
        }
        return fragment
    }

}
```

**This is my inner fragment in bottom sheet dialog fragment**

```
class TableOfContentFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentTableOfContentBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding as FragmentTableOfContentBinding
    private lateinit var coreViewModel: ReaderCoreViewModel

    private var argsNavigationItem: Array<NavigationItem>? = null
    private val tocAdapter by lazy { TableOfContentAdapter() }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            argsNavigationItem = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                it.getParcelableArray(ARGS_NAVIGATION_ITEM, NavigationItem::class.java)
            } else {
                it.getParcelableArray(ARGS_NAVIGATION_ITEM) as Array<NavigationItem>
            }

            coreViewModel = (activity as ReaderActivity).coreViewModel
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentTableOfContentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val items = argsNavigationItem?.map {
            LEVEL_INDENTATION.repeat(it.level) + it.title
        }

        with(binding) {
            rvTableOfContent.apply {
                adapter = tocAdapter
                tocAdapter.setData(
                    argsNavigationItem?.toList()
                        ?: emptyList(), items ?: listOf()
                )
                tocAdapter.setOnContentClickListener {
                    coreViewModel.navigateTo(it)
                    // what must I do in here to dismiss 'Reader Tab Fragment'...
                }
            }

            if (argsNavigationItem.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                viewEmptyToc.root.isVisible = true
                viewEmptyToc.tvTitleNotFound.setText(R.string.text_reader_toc_empty)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    companion object {
        const val LEVEL_INDENTATION = "  "

        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(args: Array<NavigationItem>) =
            TableOfContentFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putParcelableArray(ARGS_NAVIGATION_ITEM, args)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**This is my recycler view adapter for TOC**

```
class TableOfContentAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<TableOfContentAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var navItems = emptyArray<NavigationItem>()
    private var chapter = emptyArray<String>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): TableOfContentAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val binding =
            ItemTableOfContentBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TableOfContentAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(navItems[position], chapter[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = navItems.size

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemTableOfContentBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(navigationItem: NavigationItem, chapter: String) {
            with(binding) {
                tvTocTitle.text = chapter

                root.background = if (bindingAdapterPosition % 2 == 1)
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(root.context, R.color.blue_light_secondary) else
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(root.context, R.color.white)

                root.setOnClickListener { onContentClickListener?.let { it1 -> it1(navigationItem) } }
            }
        }
    }

    fun setData(newNavITem: List<NavigationItem>, newChapter: List<String>) {
        val diffUtil = DiffUtilAdapter(navItems.toList(), newNavITem)
        val diffResults = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffUtil)
        navItems = newNavITem.toTypedArray()
        chapter = newChapter.toTypedArray()
        diffResults.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

    private var onContentClickListener: ((NavigationItem) -> Unit)? = null

    fun setOnContentClickListener(listener: (NavigationItem) -> Unit) {
        onContentClickListener = listener
    }
}
```

I try to dismiss dialog in RaderTabFragment.dismissDialog() in companion object, like this.

```
fun dismissDialog() = ReaderTabFragment().dialog?.dismiss()
```

And it's not working